# Non-repeating random numbers

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on a synonym puzzle, it gives you a word and wants you to find the synonym of it given the lenght of the word. Everything works fine, but it happens on an ordered sequence; words do not appear randomly. I need `k`number of non-repeating random numbers for that. Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int k=4;
    string word[k]={"furious","tiny","untrue", "humorous", "harm"};
    string nword[k]={"angry","small","false", "funny", "damage"};
    string j;
    int point, p = 0;
    int ctr=0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randNum = (rand() % k) + 0;


    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cout << nword[i] << "\n";
        cout << "The length of the word: " << word[i].length() << "\n";
        cin>>j;



        ctr++;
        if(j==word[i])
        {
            cout<<"Correct! Score: " << i+1 << " point." << "\n\n";


        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Wrong"<<endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the variable `randNum` holds the value of the random number from 0 to k, (k is 4, combined with 0, I got 5 words). In for loop, when I set the nword and word like `nword[randNum]`, and `word[randNum]`, the result leaves a lot to be desired. First, I think there's no sync for the two (nword and word). It will apply different random numbers for the two (I might be wrong) and the second, it will be repetitive. As seen, the execution is score-based and completable, so I need non repeating questions until it reaches to `k`.

Comment: Use a for loop, check if the generated num is the same as the last one, if so redo the generation until you've reached the number of unique nums you want

Comment: One good thing is to remember what numbers were generated and when you get them skip.

Comment: @AndrewL. and then get stuck in mathematically possible infinite loop.

Comment: Fyi, `(rand() % k) + 0` generates a random number from 0..(k-1), not 0..k as you described in your question, which would be 0..3 inclusive, i.e. 0,1,2,3. And that for-loop only runs from 0..(k-1) inclusive as well, which would be 0,1,2,3; i.e. not 5 iterations, but rather 4. If that was your intention, then your opening sentence of the second paragraph is not accurate. Regarding your problem, generate a sequence of 0..4 inclusive, [shuffle it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), then iterate *that* using the items in sequence therein as indexes.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino possible, but quite rare.

Comment: Close-vote: there are a zillion + 3 ways to generate non-repeating random numbers; voted to close as too broad.

Comment: Oh, and [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), one of the more-stellar additions to C++ is what's for dinner. It's just plain awesome, and highly advised over home-rolling via `rand()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's the generalized title, my case is a bit more specific, not only about non-repetitive random number generation. Is this a print magazine, a print newspaper, or an active internet platform?

Answer (score 2):

You could shuffle your word arrays by using the [Durstenfeld shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm):

```
for(int i=k-1; i>0; i--)
{
    int j = rand() % (i+1)

    string temp = word[i];
    word[i] = word[j];
    word[j] = temp;

    temp = nword[i];
    nword[i] = nword[j];
    nword[j] = temp;
}
```

As pointed out by WhozCraig, an alternative option (arguably better, as it doesn't require permuting multiple arrays), is to create an array with indices 0..(k-1) and shuffle this array instead. This array would then contain a set of randomised indices which could be used to iterate over your word arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static const size_t k=5;
    string word[k]={"furious","tiny","untrue", "humorous", "harm"};
    string nword[k]={"angry","small","false", "funny", "damage"};
    int ctr=0;

    // build prng
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());

    // build index sequence, then shuffle
    size_t idx[k];
    std::iota(std::begin(idx), std::end(idx), 0);
    std::shuffle(std::begin(idx), std::end(idx), rng);

    for(auto i : idx)
    {
        std::string s;
        cout << nword[i] << "\n";
        cout << "The length of the word: " << word[i].length() << "\n";
        if (!(cin>>s))
            break;

        if(s==word[i])
        {
            cout<<"Correct! ";
            ++ctr;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Wrong. ";
        }
        std::cout << "Score: " << ctr << " point(s).\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error: 's' was not declared in this scope, on if (!(cin>>s)) and if (!(cin>>s)) lines.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur although I did not write this code (WhozCraig added the code upon edit), it seems to build fine for me. Did you directly copy/paste the code, or did you integrate each line manually? Ensure you have `string s` declaration at the top of your main loop.

Comment: Just compiled the code, yeah I copied and the pasted the latter. It's still not random, have you tried it?

Comment: Playing with code for hours and still get ordered patterns :(